# Adding a column on R dataframe with NA values

Tags: r, na

I have a data frame name df on R:

```
    a                       b           c   d
1   BR073ELAC5EIANID-115781 2014-04-14  7   3   
2   BR073ELAC5EIANID-115781 2014-04-15  NA  NA  
3   BR073ELAC5EIANID-115781 2014-04-16  6   3   
4   BR073ELAC5EIANID-115781 2014-04-17  5   2   
5   BR073ELAC5EIANID-115781 2014-04-18  2   3
```

And I would like to add a column equal to 1 if column c = NA and if column d = NA
I try the following :

```
df$e <- (if(is.na(df$c) && is.na(df$d)) 1 else 0)
```

but I get all the column e equal to 1

Comment: `df$e <- ifelse(is.na(df$c) & is.na(df$d), 1, 0)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid `ifelse`, just use `&`

```
> df$e <- 1*(is.na(df$c) & is.na(df$d))
> df
                        a          b  c  d e
1 BR073ELAC5EIANID-115781 2014-04-14  7  3 0
2 BR073ELAC5EIANID-115781 2014-04-15 NA NA 1
3 BR073ELAC5EIANID-115781 2014-04-16  6  3 0
4 BR073ELAC5EIANID-115781 2014-04-17  5  2 0
5 BR073ELAC5EIANID-115781 2014-04-18  2  3 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach using logical indexing:

```
as.numeric(is.na(df$c) & is.na(df$d))

## [1] 0 1 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Or

```
df$e <- 1*(rowSums(is.na(df[,3:4]))==2)
 df$e
 #[1] 0 1 0 0 0
```